# Next.js large first load JS size

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to build my project with translation i18n.

I make a custom hook for my project.

```js
import useTranslationDefault from 'next-translate/useTranslation';
    
export default function useTranslation(namespaces?: string) {
   return useTranslationDefault(namespaces || 'common');
}
```

But when I try to use it and build, I got red first load

[image]

Does anyone know why that happens? And is there another way to make it better?

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: You are using some heavy libraries in your custom `_app`. Analyze your bundle using this: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/analyze-bundles or https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-webpack-bundle-size-analyzer

Comment: I found the solution, just add dynamic import in _app.js , thanks